# Cachin jquery objects simple code

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'm trying to implement caching and reduced DOM manipulation into my very complex JS code. I just want to make sure, what's more efficient?

1)

```
var $thebox = $(".textbox[data-title*='"+dt+"']");

    $thebox.remove();
```

or

2) `$(".textbox[data-title*='"+dt+"']").remove();` ?

Comment: http://jsperf.com is a great tool to find out the performance of js snippets.

Comment: Also, there's the profiler built in to Chrome, and now maybe other browsers.

Comment: `$(".textbox.something']").remove();` the most efficient. Searching by attributes is not the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same if you use $(".textbox[data-title*='"+dt+"']") one time.

It up to your case. If you **have to** re-new **'selector'** before remove all of them.

You have to use $(".textbox[data-title*='"+dt+"']").remove();

Because $thebox is old now.